# Please Help Me Identify Mystery Seed

Tags: identification, seeds, maple, cherries

If thou art be courageous, please help this villager identify these mystery seeds. The peddler(got it online) sayeth they be sakura seeds, but methinks it might not be the case.

[image: seeds to be identified]

See those black pointy ones? That's the one in question.

Bonus Quest!: Do the other seeds look like Japanese Red Maple and Green Maple?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like black oil sunflower seeds. It is difficult to judge size given the reference points available, sunflower would be roughly 1 cm. long and good thick solid seeds.

Maple seeds usually have single wings. Those in the pic do not.